# Office365 ユーザーフォーム テキストコントロールの文字の異常について

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

ユーザーフォームに設けたテキストボックスの字形が Topプロパティのある値前後で字形が勝手に変わる問題です。
なぜ変わるのかわからないままシートや他のコントロール、コードを消していったところ、どうやら、条件が多少絞られてきました。

試した環境：
自作PCとdynabook V272/HL のWindows 10 Pro (64bit)

1. テキストボックスを一つ以上
2. テキストのフォントサイズ9,書体は HS UI Gothic や MS明朝などで英数字や漢字などを入れ
3. テキストボックスの Height は16　でTopをほぼ22にすると、文字のサイズが 10になる

Topは、21.9や22.1でもこの現象は発生します。

大した不具合ではないですが、ひょっとして解決方法があればお教えください。

日本のMicrosoft Answerには聞くだけ無駄としか思えないどうでもいいような回答しか返ってこないのに、このまえ始めたばかりのPythonのことでここでお聞きしたら、すぐに、回答をいくつもいただいて感謝しています。

上から2行目のテキストボックスの文字サイズが大きくなってます:
[image: 上から2行目のテキストボックスの文字サイズが大きくなってます]

ひょっとして2台試したとはいえ、自分の環境の所為かも知れないので異常の発生したファイルを上げておきます
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtdppjRUZ9VxiLpenrftHY5ZNpOqDQ?e=dSLiCA

Comment: .テキストボックスの Height,Topはデザイナでその値に設定してもそうなるのですか？コードで変更したらそうなるのですか？